# Get string path properties from object path clearly in C#

Tags: c#, properties, classname

i need to have this result :

```
ProgrammeEtude.Description
```

So, i have done something like that and it work

```
modelMember = $"{nameof(Gabarit.ProgrammeEtude)}.{nameof(Gabarit.ProgrammeEtude.Description)}";
```

But it's ugly and if we have more than one class to reach, it will not be clean. So,  i would like to know if it's possible to create a function to get the fullName property without the first class clearly. Only by calling a function

```
// Like that
modelMember = typeof(ProgrammeEtude).GetPropertyFullName(nameof(ProgrammeEtude.Description));

// Or like that
modelMember = GetPropertyFullName(ProgrammeEtude.Description);
```

Thank you!

**Final solution help By Ecoron :**

```
public void Test1()
        {
            var result = NameOf<Gabarit>(x => x.ProgrammeEtude.Description);

        }

        public static string NameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
        {
            return string.Join(".", selector.ToString().Split('.').Skip(1));

        }
```

Comment: There is no such concept as "full name of a property" - so whatever you would like to implement you have to write yourself. Note that true "full name" probably should include full namespace and assembly name/version to match class "full name". On other hand it looks like you already have a way to achieve what you want and looking for some syntax sugar to write it differently - please [edit] question to clarify your problem/goal.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in runtime:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass Other;
}

public class Tests
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        var result = NameOf<SomeClass>(x => x.Other.Other.Other);
    }

    public static string NameOf<T>(Expression<Func<T,object>> selector)
    {
        const string joinWith = ".";
        return nameof(T) + joinWith + string.Join(joinWith, selector.ToString().Split('.').Skip(1));
    }
}
```

Result: *SomeClass.Other.Other.Other*

You can play with this function to get desired result - with/out namespaces/indexes/separation select just start or end or skip something, etc.

Be aware that this working great only if you don't use some funky variables/enums inside which accessed by dot. For more correct version you should traverse expression yourself, but in this example Im just kinda lazy to write this all, and better to use simple approach.

Comment: ````return String.Join(".", typeof(T).Name, selector.Body.ToString().Substring(selector.Parameters[0].Name.Length+1))```` hacks the same in ````NameOf```` :)

Comment: Thank you very much. It work.

Comment: @cly, yeah, your version is more optimal